# Set default value to variation dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set the default value for a product that has 2 attributes: 1st is the size and the 2nd is a city. so this product has a price for each city which the city will be in the cookies. so what I've tried and failed and still trying is set
 `pa_city = $_cookie['city']`. I just want to set default for pa_city and let customer choose from pa_size. I tried using jquery and it worked but that won't work if customer change city from setting and cart still full. so guys please help me this is my beginning in woocommerce.

Comment: figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. i used selected in variable.php to force selected value.
and clear cart if setting change. so no conflict price appears.